# PHP laravel query database every 1 mintue

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel

I want to query a mysql table in my project in every 1 minute. I used javascript **setInterval** method for timing and ajax for sending request and receives output as html. but there is many problems with it:
1- whole website goes very slow only for performing this action.
2- with this I can't query something else from database.
my code is :

```
 function ajaxGetAllOrders(){
$.ajax('<?php echo url()?>/admin/getAllOrders',{
  dataType:'json',
  async: true,
  success:function(data){
    $('#page-content').html(data.content);
  }
  });
}
```

and interval method:

```
 $(function(){
   setInterval('ajaxGetAllOrders();',60000);
   ajaxGetAllOrders();
});
```

I tried to create another connection to database for this but it wont help anyway.

and the php getAllOrders method:

```
public function getAllOrders(){
    if (!$this->isAdmin()){
        return;
    }
    $fields = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('z_orders')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    $nFields = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('z_food_orders')->orderBy('id','desc')->get();
    $count=0;
    $i=1;
    if (count($fields)>0){
        foreach($fields as $field){
            $userid = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('z_users')->whereId($field->user_id)->first();
            $data['username']=$userid->name;
            $data['address'] = $userid->address;
            $orderId = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('z_food_orders')->whereOrderId($field->id)->first();
            $foodId = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('z_foods')->whereId($orderId->food_id)->first();
            $data['foodname'] =$foodId->title;
            $data['foodcount'] = $orderId->foodcount;
            $foodPrice = $foodId->price;
            $count += $foodPrice * $orderId->foodcount;
            $i++;
        }
        $cid = DB::connection('mysql2')->table('z_users')->whereId($userid->id)->first();
        $data['customer_id'] = $cid->cctt;
        $data['price']=$count;
        $data['fields']=$nFields;
    }
    return response()->json(['content'=>view('admin.orders',$data)->render()]);
}
```

the whole idea behind this is user orders something.then in admin panel in orders section admin can see all orders. so i want to able that admin won't reload page and in every minute the list of orders show new orders.

Comment: Can you show the php code for `/admin/getAllOrders`? Have you tried to debug the request using the developer tools from your browser?

Comment: What is the reason to query your database every minute? That doesn't sound optimal. Are you trying to auto-refresh a page that contains certain information?

Comment: it's renders a page that showing the orders purchased

Comment: 1. The fact that your website works slowly is kind of a general statement so please clarify: is the request to `getAllOrders` slow or are all requests slow? (if you have lots of orders and you fetch them all then it's not surprising for it to be slow, so in that case you should use pagination). 2. The fact that you can't query something else is also not explained thoroughly, so please give an example. Also it would help if you explained what you're trying to achieve in more detail.

Comment: You want something like a websocket....

Comment: edited for more details

Comment: @Pogrindis is right, [Websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) is the best approach here. You can use [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/) to implement websockets with PHP.

Comment: Why are you retrieving all orders every time? Surely you would only need the latest subset? Couldn't you implement some kind of paging and only retrieve the latest 50 orders at a time from your ajax script?So when you refresh the view, just store the last retrieved id and work out where you need to query for new orders from that. Though I agree with the others that you should look at websockets

Comment: problem is in this moment orders table only includes 13 orders. so it's not very heavy

Comment: It makes much more sense to use WebSockets to notify the client that they should ask server for new order list, rather than querying every minute..

Comment: While something like websockets might be a better architecture for this sort of thing, it wouldn't help with performance in this case. Performing a bunch of queries inside loops iterating over the results of other queries is a pretty big performance killer. Maybe you should create relationships between users, orders and food?